# Why can't I use this command in my resource dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I cannot create my class in this dictionary. Intellisense isn't picking up my `WindowCommand<T>` class. I checked the Assembly name and it appears to be correct, no typos in the namespace either. What's making it choke?

WindowCommand.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

using Ninject;
using Premier;
using Premier.View;

namespace Premier.Command
{
    public class WindowCommand<T> : Command where T : Window
    {
        private Func<bool> focus;
        private int instantiationCount;

        public bool IsDialog { get; set; }
        public bool Multiple { get; set; }

        public WindowCommand()
        {
        }

        public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            var instantiatedOnce = instantiationCount > 0;

            if (!Multiple && instantiatedOnce)
            {
                focus();
                return;
            }

            instantiationCount++;

            var w = App.Kernel.Get<T>();
            w.Closed += (s, e) => instantiationCount--;
            focus = w.Focus;

            if (IsDialog)
                w.ShowDialog();
            else
                w.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

Windows.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Premier.Command;assembly=PremierAutoDataExtractor"
                    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:Premier.View;assembly=PremierAutoDataExtractor"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <c:WindowCommand x:Key="ReportsPurchased" x:TypeArguments="v:PurchasedReportsView" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x:TypeArguments` XAML directive is not supported in XAML 2006 (xml namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation`) on non-root XAML elements. If you want to use `x:TypeArguments` on a non-root XAML element, you should use XAML2009 (xml namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/presentation`). However, again it is only supported for non-complied loose XAML.

Text from MSDN Page:

> In WPF and when targeting .NET Framework 4, you can use XAML 2009
>   features together with x:TypeArguments but only for loose XAML (XAML
>   that is not markup-compiled). Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the
>   BAML form of XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and
>   features. If you need to markup compile the XAML, you must operate
>   under the restrictions noted in the "XAML 2006 and WPF Generic XAML
>   Usages" section.

So, I am afraid, you cannot use your `WindowCommand` in a resource dictionary.

Link to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476.aspx) page for more information on `x:TypeArguments` directive.